# Python Pandas compare two dataframes to assign country to phone number

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, startswith

I have two dataframes that I read in via csv. Dataframe one consists of a phone number and some additional data. The second dataframe contains country codes and country names.

I want to take the phone number from the first dataset and compare it to the country codes of the second. Country codes can between one to four digits long. I go from the longest country code to the shortest. If there is a match, I want to assign the country name to the phone number.

Input longlist:

```
phonenumber, add_info    
34123425209, info1
92654321762, info2
12018883637, info3
6323450001, info4
496789521134, info5
```

Input country_list:

```
country;country_code;order_info
Spain;34;1
Pakistan;92;4
USA;1;2
Philippines;63;3
Germany;49;4
Poland;48;1
Norway;47;2
```

Output should be:

```
phonenumber, add_info, country, order_info    
34123425209, info1, Spain, 1
92654321762, info2, Pakistan, 4
12018883637, info3, USA, 2
6323450001, info4, Philippines, 3
496789521134, info5, Germany, 4
```

I have it solved once like this:

```
#! /usr/bin/python
import csv
import pandas
with open ('longlist.csv','r') as lookuplist:
with open ('country_list.csv','r') as inputlist:
    with open('Outputfile.csv', 'w') as outputlist:
        reader = csv.reader(lookuplist, delimiter=',')
        reader2 = csv.reader(inputlist, delimiter=';')
        writer = csv.writer(outputlist, dialect='excel')

        for i in reader2:
            for xl in reader:
                if xl[0].startswith(i[1]):
                    zeile = [xl[0], xl[1], i[0], i[1], i[2]]
                    writer.writerow(zeile)
            lookuplist.seek(0)
```

But I would like to solve this problem, using pandas. What I got to work:
- Read in the csv files
- Remove duplicates from "longlist" 
- Sort list of countries / country code

This is, what I have working already:

```
import pandas as pd, numpy as np
longlist = pd.read_csv('path/to/longlist.csv', 
                                 usecols=[2,3], names=['PHONENUMBER','ADD_INFO'])
country_list = pd.read_csv('path/to/country_list.csv', 
                           sep=';', names=['COUNTRY','COUNTRY_CODE','ORDER_INFO'], skiprows=[0])

# remove duplicates and make phone number an index
longlist = longlist.drop_duplicates('PHONENUMBER')
longlist = longlist.set_index('PHONENUMBER')

# Sort country list, from high to low value and make country code an index
country_list=country_list.sort_values(by='COUNTRY_CODE', ascending=0)
country_list=country_list.set_index('COUNTRY_CODE')

(...)

longlist.to_csv('path/to/output.csv')
```

But any way trying the same with datasets does not work. I cannot apply startswith (cannot iterate through objects and cannot apply it on objects). I would really appreciate your help.

Comment: Try always to provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) when asking questions. In case of _pandas_ questions please provide sample _input_ and _output_ data sets (5-7 rows in CSV/dict/JSON/Python code format _as text_, so one could use it when coding an answer for you). This will help to avoid _situations_ like: `your code isn't working for me` or `it doesn't work with my data`, etc.

Comment: Hi MaxU, you comment makes a lot of sense of course. So I tried to provide the inputs and outputs. Since my initial attempt, the input file slightly changed. So I had to adapt the "startswith" command, but I did not have the chance to test it, before posting. I am confident though, that it is ok.

Comment: I think the problem is parse `country_code` from `phonenumber`. Is possible use table - [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_country_calling_codes#Alphabetical_listing_by_country_or_region) - but some as canada and USA have equal code - 1. So then what is output?

Comment: jezrael: I basically have the table you were linking to in my country_code table. I only need to recognize 56 countries. USA/CAN can be treated as one country in this step. My problem starts, when I have a phone number and now have to figure out, which country code matches the start of the phone number. The length of the country codes can differ, as is also shown nicely in your link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i would do it this way:

```
cl = pd.read_csv('country_list.csv', sep=';', dtype={'country_code':str})
ll = pd.read_csv('phones.csv', skipinitialspace=True, dtype={'phonenumber':str})

lookup = cl['country_code']
lookup.index = cl['country_code']

ll['country_code'] = (
    ll['phonenumber']
    .apply(lambda x: pd.Series([lookup.get(x[:4]), lookup.get(x[:3]),
                                lookup.get(x[:2]), lookup.get(x[:1])]))
    .apply(lambda x: x.get(x.first_valid_index()), axis=1)
)

# remove `how='left'` parameter if you don't need "unmatched" phone-numbers    
result = ll.merge(cl, on='country_code', how='left')
```

Output:

```
In [195]: result
Out[195]:
    phonenumber add_info country_code      country  order_info
0   34123425209    info1           34        Spain         1.0
1   92654321762    info2           92     Pakistan         4.0
2   12018883637    info3            1          USA         2.0
3   12428883637   info31         1242      Bahamas         3.0
4    6323450001    info4           63  Philippines         3.0
5  496789521134    info5           49      Germany         4.0
6   00000000000      BAD         None          NaN         NaN
```

Explanation:

```
In [216]: (ll['phonenumber']
   .....:   .apply(lambda x: pd.Series([lookup.get(x[:4]), lookup.get(x[:3]),
   .....:                               lookup.get(x[:2]), lookup.get(x[:1])]))
   .....: )
Out[216]:
      0     1     2     3
0  None  None    34  None
1  None  None    92  None
2  None  None  None     1
3  1242  None  None     1
4  None  None    63  None
5  None  None    49  None
6  None  None  None  None
```

phones.csv: - i've intentionally added one Bahamas number (`1242...`) and one invalid number (`00000000000`)

```
phonenumber, add_info
34123425209, info1
92654321762, info2
12018883637, info3
12428883637, info31
6323450001, info4
496789521134, info5
00000000000, BAD
```

Comment: MaxU: Thank you. I hope I can check this by Friday and then come back to it. I will definitely have to study on the lambda function. Your output file definitely looks like what I am looking for. For just looking at it: If I had a country code of the length of "5", I would have to add a "lookup.get(x[:5]). Correct?

Comment: @SLglider, you are welcome. Yes, you would have to add it in front (as a first one), but as far as i know, currently - 4 digits is a maximum  ;)

Comment: Ok, I could verify it and it worked. And I guess I am understanding it to the most part. I do not have to sort the country_code list any longer, as this is done in the "pd.Series" part, right? (Btw. if you want to filter i.e. for the Channel Islands, you have longer "country"-codes).
How can I filter the unmatched countries, so I do not have them in my results?

Comment: @SLglider, i've added a comment to the code: `#remove `how='left'` parameter if you don't need "unmatched" phone-numbers`. That means that your result set will contain only matched phone numbers