# Find value that is a subset to a row in Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

This is ascutally a follow up solution / question to one of my other questions: [Python Pandas compare two dataframes to assign country to phone number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37665457/python-pandas-compare-two-dataframes-to-assign-country-to-phone-number)

We have two data frames:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({"TEL": ["49123410", "49123411","49123412","49123413","49123414","49123710", "49123810"]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({"BASE_NR": ["491234","491237","491238"],"NAME": ["A","B","C"]})
```

What I want to do is to assign on of the df2 Names to the df1 TEL. If we take the first value "491234", we see that the first five list entries in df1 start exactly on this string. This should result in something like this:

```
|   | TEL      | PREFIX |
| 0 | 49123410 | 491234 |
| 1 | 49123411 | 491234 |
| 2 | 49123412 | 491234 |
| 3 | 49123413 | 491234 |
| 4 | 49123414 | 491234 |
| 5 | 49123710 | 491237 |
| 6 | 49123810 | 491238 |
```

Other than in [Python Pandas compare two dataframes to assign country to phone number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37665457/python-pandas-compare-two-dataframes-to-assign-country-to-phone-number)

I developed another approach that works much faster:

```
for i, s in df2.iterrows():
    df1.loc[df1["TEL"].str.startswith(s[0], na=False), "PREFIX"] = s[0]
```

So far, it worked perfectly and I have been using it over and over again, as I have to match many different sources on phone numbers and their subsets. But lately, I am experiencing more and more issues. The PREFIX column will be setup but stays empty. No matches are found any longer, where I had about 150.000 before.

Is there something fundamental that I am missing and was it only luck it worked this way? Input files (I am reading them in from a csv) and data types have not changed. I also have not changed the Pandas version (22).

PS: What also would be helpful is an idea, how to debug that part that happens here:

```
df1.loc[df1["TEL"].str.startswith(s[0], na=False), "PREFIX"] = s[0]
```

Comment: Your code works with the data you've provided. Can you give us some data to demonstrate where your logic fails? In other words, a [mcve]?

Comment: Or why not just use `df1.TEL.str[:-2]`?

Comment: Because the lengths differ. This was just a very simplified example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well if it is speed you are after, this should be faster:

```
mapping = dict(zip(df2['BASE_NR'].tolist(), df2['NAME'].tolist()))

def getName(tel):
    for k, v in mapping.items():
        if tel.startswith(k):
            return k, v
    return '', ''

df1['BASE_NR'], df1['NAME'] = zip(*df1['TEL'].apply(getName))
```

Comment: Hi Zipa, your solution goes "a bit" beyond my current Python knowledge. Could you please elaborate a bit why it is better? What I think I understood is that you create a dict which is usually a faster approach, as everything is loaded into memory? Am I on the right track?
Other than that, my question was not only about speed. But I had a strange behavior where I was looking for an explanation. I figured it out myself by now. It was a "simple" typo. I hope to find some time soon to try your solution.

Comment: @SLglider This is some sort of custom join where you have a dict of `BASE_NR` pointing to respective names. Given that `BASE_NR` is not exact match `TEL` this code goes trough dict and if `TEL` starts with key (`BASE_NR`) it immediately returns it's key/value pair. If no match was found it returns empty strings for both. Hopefully you'll find this helpful :)